# Is there a way to do Swift's Protocol Composition in Kotlin

Tags: swift, kotlin, interface, protocols, swift-protocols

So for Swift we can create new types or pass to a method as a parameters using the `&` operator.

Example Swift Code:

```
protocol Fooable {}
protocol Barable {}

// the new protocol
typealias FooBarable = Fooable & Barable

// method parameter 
func doSomethingFor(object: Fooable & Barable) { ... }
```

Is there a way to do this in Kotlin's Interfaces?

- [Kotlin Interfaces Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html)
- [Swift Protocols Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check the below code:

```
interface A{

}

interface B{

}

fun <T> check(variable: T) where T : A, T: B{
    print("Hello");
}
```

the above gives you compile time error if you try to pass a variable which doesn't confirm to both of them

Answer (score 3):

From the function side you'd be able to handle it with generic functions using a [`where`-clause](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html):

```
fun <T> foo(obj: T) where T: Fooable, T: Barable {
    ...
}
```